# Stashing a tag to use with Solspace tag entries

Tags: stash, solspace-tag

I have a template that sets some stash values from a campign entry, such as campaigntag. This custom field is just a text input. What i'm then trying to do on the page is show a bunch of entries from another channel using the campaigntag as follows;

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="campaign"
    status="open"
    limit="1"
}
{exp:stash:set_value name="campaigntag" value="{campaign_tag}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:tag:entries
    channel="event"
    status="open"
    orderby="title"
    sort="asc"
    paginate="bottom"
    limit="9"
    tag="{exp:stash:campaigntag}"
}
{title}
{/exp:tag:entries}
```

For some reason, I can't get any entries to display when I use a stash variable in the tag="". I can get results if I hard code the tag in here.

Wondered if someone might be able to help figure out what's going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to promote my Stash tags up to first-class citizens in terms of parse order - Something like this will put the Stash tags on an even footing, saving you from having to figure out complicated black magic parse-order convolutions like `parse="inward"`:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="campaign-vars" parse_tags="yes"}    
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="campaign"
        status="open"
        limit="1"
    }
       {stash:campaigntag}{campaign_tag}{/stash:campaigntag}
       ...
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="campaign-vars"}
    {exp:tag:entries
        channel="event"
        status="open"
        orderby="title"
        sort="asc"
        paginate="bottom"
        limit="9"
        tag="{campaigntag}"
    }
       {title}
    {/exp:tag:entries}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```